# Need a drop-down to be a certain width on page load, but then show full length of content when clicked

Tags: css, overflow, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down that needs to be a specific width.  The problem is that the content in the drop-down is longer than the width so some of it gets hidden on IE browsers (Chrome for example actually makes the drop-down area longer when clicked.

I thought of using hidden overflow, but then the drop-down arrow disappears.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100px;overflow:hidden;">
<select name="ed">
<option selected>[select]</option>
<option value="">word g g fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
<option value="">ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the overflow on to the select box itself.

And user overflow-y hidden:

http://jsfiddle.net/dKmU5/

```
<select name="ed" style="width:100px;overflow-y:hidden;">
```

My mistake... to get this working in IE7/8, you'll need a touch of javascript. Please check out this link:

http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2008/05/Viewing-Option-Text-in-IE7-thats-Wider-than-the-Select-List.cfm